# css width of column header not correct after js read more/less

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve a point where the column width of the header follows thru the width of the row when the **Show (+)** or (-) is clicked to expand or shorten the text after 20 characters.

[image: how should look]

Now what happens, in reality, is that the column width of the table header does not follow the width of a row; not when the page is default loaded and not when Show(+)/(-) is clicked - except when you click Show on the row which has the widest text which column header is following by width.

[image: incorrect width]

Here's what possible css influences the table.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="mainTable" style=" white-space: word-wrap: break-word;" cellspacing="0">
```

And there's some CSS being applied to the tr/tbody of this table.

```
  .truncate {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;}
```

Here's how HTML looks when inspected for th and td. Just in case.

[image: html of th and td]

And this is how js function looks:

```js
$(function() {
  var showTotalChar = 20,
    showChar = "Show (+)",
    hideChar = "Hide (-)";

  $('.show-more-less').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).text();

    if (content.length > showTotalChar) {
      var con = content.substr(0, showTotalChar);
      var hcon = content.substr(showTotalChar, content.length - showTotalChar);
      var txt = con + '<span class="dots">...</span><span class="morectnt"><span>' + hcon + '</span><a href="" class="showmoretxt">' + showChar + '</a></span>';

      $(this).html(txt);
    }

  });
  $(".showmoretxt").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("sample")) {

      $(this).removeClass("sample");
      $(this).text(showChar);

    } else {

      $(this).addClass("sample");
      $(this).text(hideChar);

    }

    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();

    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But I'm fairly certain that its not fault of the js because it works on another dataTable perfectly on another page.

My three main approaches to finding solution until now have been;

1. Removing class and styles one by one in hope of finding a cure
2. Trying to gloss with bootstrap over it with things like flex
3. Trying to play with custom styles

But so far no results.

Now I've omitted lot of code here which by my opinion is not important, to make this more readable (#programmersanitymatter), but if you need more info please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: is it possible to post the code as a snippet

Comment: It would be good if you could create a minimal example that reproduces the error and post it in your question as a snippet. For example, from the above I'm assuming the `style="width: 260.006px"` on the `th` element was generated by the browser, but I can't be sure until I see the code.